# Different menus based on current node taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-navigation

I was wondering if anyone could give me some insight on the best way to structure my site for this situation. A little bit of background: I am working on a large enterprise site with a lot of sub sections; thus a lot of menus. We are using the page manager with panels instead of blocks.

The URLs for our site will be structured using pathauto with something like: [term:vocabulary]/[term:parent:parent:name]/[term:parent:name]/[term:name]):

Each of these paths should be based on a "hierarchy" taxonomy which each node will have defined.

So the hierarchy vocabulary will have the following terms:

```
main section 1
    subsection 1_1
    subjection 1_2
        subsection1_2_1
main section 2
    subsection 2_1
    subsection 2_2
```

Now for the question: each of these paths/taxonomy terms will have a specific menu which need to be displayed. Would you have any suggestions on how to dynamically change the menu based on the page's taxonomy?

I've looked into the "Taxonomy menu" module, but from what I understand it actually creates your menus based on a list of taxonomy. This is not what we want.. (we'd like to have seperate menus created and pull those out based on taxonomy).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest using, creating content along with a single normal menu(including heirarchy) and then use [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block)

But if you have already decided on using taxonomy for the paths, then

1. Create multiple menus.
2. Create a dynamic block through a custom module.
3. Within the custom block, based on the taxonomy term, decide which menu to render and then use the function [menu_tree_all_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7) to get the particular menu and then render it.

I think that should do the trick.